# Regression: Scatterplot with low R squared and high p-values

Tags: dataset, regression

Based on three datasets, I have produced the scatterplot below in Python:
[image]

I am trying to fit a line on each dataset, but when I check the metrics this is what I get:

- Set 1 (red):     R squared=0.002, p-value=0.651
- Set 2 (purple):  R squared=0.008, p-value=0.378
- Set 3 (blue):    R squared=0.001, p-value=0.714

**My question:** are such data sets impossible to fit? Is there any kind of data transformation I could apply, based on the scatterplot shape?

The goal is to predict from regression.

Comment: There's an infinite number of transformations, eventually you can find one that can give you any answer you want. Just ignore the fact you chose a transformation from the infinity of transformations when you write it up with your significant p-value.

Comment: Less sarcastic response: What is the question you are asking of the data? Chasing transformations to get a "good fit" or a large R-squared is not the way we do statistics.

Comment: I didn't mean to force a fit - I just wanted to make sure there is any.

Comment: You can fit a line to any data. Are you trying to determine trend, predict from regression, cluster, classify, ...?

Comment: I wanted to predict from regression.

Comment: The data certainly appears non-linear. Have you considered regression trees (CART)?

Comment: Would this bring me to a point where I come up with a prediction model (equation) or something? I also wonder what the applicability limits of such an approach are.

Comment: Basically it gives you a conjunction_of_features => value. The decision boundaries are linear. See here for details. http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/350-2006/lecture-10.pdf

Comment: Just eyeballing the blue squares, it looks no different to a random scatterplot. Whatever value of X you give me, I'll tell you the Y value is equally likely to be anywhere between 0 and 7000. That data just has *no* predictive power. The purple look the same and the red is impossible to tell because the graphic is not well designed. Show the three sets of data on separate plots because they tell different stories.

Comment: If you provide some of the data we can test it out.  At first glance it looks like  the data are in a polar coordinate system.  Plot the data in cartesian coordinates  assuming that x and y are polar coordinates.  If there is, do a regression between the new cartesian variables.

Comment: As your data look non-linear and you want to use linear regression, have you tried the popular [kernel trick](https://towardsdatascience.com/truly-understanding-the-kernel-trick-1aeb11560769).